# Javascript how to identify a combination of letters and strip a portion of it

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Im very new to Regex . Right now im trynig to use regex to prepare my markup string before sending it to the database.

Here is an example string:

```
@[admin](user:3) Testing this string @[hellotessginal](user:4) Hey!
```

So far i am able to identify `@[admin](user:3)` the entire term here using `/@\[(.*?)]\((.*?):(\d+)\)/g`

But the next step forward is that i wish to remove the `(user:3)` leaving me with `@[admin]`.

Hence the result of passing through the stripper function would be:

```
@[admin] Testing this string @[hellotessginal] Hey!
```

Please help!

Comment: Why don't you capture `@\[(.*?)]` then? Something like `s.replace(/(@\[.*?])\(.*?:\d+\)/g, '$1')` could do. I would use negated character classes instead of `.` here, though, `s.replace(/(@\[[^\][]*])\([^()]*?:\d+\)/g, '$1')`

Comment: Im sorry for being a noob @WiktorStribiżew  , what does s.replace do? could you assist my understanding by writing a function that i can tinker with?

Comment: @Mandy8055 yup but theres a possibility that the user types in their own paranthesis , which is why the pattern needs to have a condition to have the @[...] infront of the parenthesis

Comment: `s` is a string variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
s.replace(/(@\[[^\][]*])\([^()]*?:\d+\)/g, '$1')
```

See the *[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ThaYU/1)*. **Details**:

- `(@\[[^\][]*])` - Capturing group 1: `@[`, 0 or more digits other than `[` and `]` as many as possible and then `]`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*?` - 0 or more (but as few as possible) chars other than `(` and `)`
- `:` - a colon
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The `$1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured in Group 1.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const rx = /(@\[[^\][]*])\([^()]*?:\d+\)/g;
const remove_parens = (string, regex) => string.replace(regex, '$1');

let s = '@[admin](user:3) Testing this string @[hellotessginal](user:4) Hey!';
s = remove_parens(s, rx);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly , however may i ask why did u do a replacement with '$1'

Comment: @neowenshun If I do not use it, I will remove the text matched. However, we need to keep the `@` and the subsequent `[...]` substring in the result. That is why it is captured into a group (with ID=1, capturing groups are 1-indexed), and the `$1` backreference is used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, great explanation. I've learned a new thing as well. Upvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var str = "@[admin](user:3) Testing this string @[hellotessginal](user:4) Hey!";
str = str.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, ' ');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for replying. If im not wrong, this regex does not have the condition that the `@[...]` is infront of it am i right?

Comment: @neowenshun, Yes. It will remove all the things within the parentheses.

Comment: @neowenshun See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ThaYU/2).

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Right, the issue is that i only wish to remove it if it follows the `@[...]` as the user may type in some messages in the parenthesis

Comment: Probably, I have misunderstood your problem. Ok got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
str.replace(/(?<=\@\[(.*?)\])\(.*?:\d+\)/g, ' ');
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPPCEA/1/)

I've assumed the strings for which `"admin"` and `"user"` are placeholders  in the example cannot contain the characters in the string `"()[]"`. If that's not the case please leave a comment and I will adjust the regex.

I've kept the first capture group on the assumption that it is needed for some unstated purpose. If it's not needed, remove it:

```
(?<=\@\[.*?\])\(.*?:\d+\)
```

There is of course no point creating a capture group for a substring that is to be replaced with an empty string.

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=         : begin positive lookbehind
  \@\[       : match '@['
  (.*?)      : match 0+ chars, lazily, save to capture group 1
  \]         : match ']'
)            : end positive lookbehind
\(.*?:\d+\)  : match '(', 0+ chars, lazily, 1+ digits, ')'
```